# Error When Restarting Thin for my Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, thin

I am trying to use the folling command to restart thin.

```
thin restart -c config/thin.yml
```

Here's the content of thin.yml:

```
rackup: /root/SEHabitat/config.ru
pid: /tmp/pids/thin.pid
wait: 30
timeout: 600
log: /root/SEHabitat/log/thin.log
max_conns: 1024
require: []

max_persistent_conns: 512
environment: production
servers: 3
daemonize: true
#chdir: /root/SEHabitat
socket: /tmp/thin.sock
#port: 3000
```

Here's the output:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/runner.rb:171:in `chdir': Not a directory - /root/SEHabitat/config/thin.yml (Errno::ENOTDIR)
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/runner.rb:171:in `run_command'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thin-1.2.11/bin/thin:6
from /usr/bin/thin:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/thin:19
```

Comment: show the content of config/thin.yml

Comment: I have edited to show the content of thin.yml, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Option "-c" is to change dir, you have to use upercase "-C" to specify config file. LIke `thin config -C /etc/thin/myapp.yml -c /var/`